# How to create a checkbox in OpenXava?

Tags: java, frameworks, openxava

I'm evaluation OpenXava. Is it possible to create a check box using OpenXava? How could I do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the `.jsp` and add what you need.

For a checkbox you can add this to your `.jsp`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="val" />
```

Comment: Is there any annotations for that?

Comment: No, it is just an HTML element.  I believe you will use events to manage it something like OnSelectElementAction.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to define a boolean property in your entity module (persisted or transient) and OpenXava will draw a CheckBox by default for that property in the views you include that property (of course).

Then, if you want to react to changes to that CheckBox, you can use the @OnChange() annotation for this property and link the event to your custom "On change action".

Please, read or test the multiple examples that there are available.

Try adding a boolean property to some entity of [the quick star guide](http://openxava.wikispaces.com/quick-start_en) and you will see (remember to update the DB schema if the property is not transient).